# need to find a string from a file with a .crv extension in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a task to get all the files from a directory , read the files find if the files contain anything with extension .crv. I have written the following code using Python but there is something wrong the code runs infintely. Can some help me in identifying what could possibly be wrong.

```
for file in os.listdir(location):
try:
    if file.endswith(".cxx"):
        #print "crvfile found:\t", file
        filepath = location+"\\"+file
        #print filepath
        cxxopenfile = open(filepath,"r")                
        for line in crvopenfile:
            line = line.rstrip()
            find = re.findall('^\S*(['.crv']+), line)
            #if len(find) > 0:
v
v
        cxxopenfile.close()
        cxxfiles.append(str(file))
        counter = counter+1   
except Exception as e:
    raise e
    print "No files found here!"
```

print "Total files found:\t", counter

Comment: Hi Divya, please see the answer. I tested with two test dummy test files and works fine. Please let me know if you need further help and do not forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import re
from os import listdir

location = "c:\\git\\repos\\test-code"
counter = 0
for file in os.listdir(location):
    try:
        if file.endswith(".cxx"):
            #print "crvfile found:\t", file
            filepath = location+"\\"+file
            #print filepath
            cxxopenfile = open(filepath,"r")                
            for line in cxxopenfile:
                line = line.rstrip()
                find = re.findall("^\S*['.crv']+", line)
                if len(find) > 0:
                    #cxxfiles.append(str(file))
                    counter = counter+1
                else:
                    print "No extension .crv found!"    
            cxxopenfile.close()            
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
        print "No files found here!"
print "Total files found:\t", counter
```

Results:

```
$ python ./test.py
No extension .crv found!
No extension .crv found!
No extension .crv found!
Total files found:      2
```

Comment: Hi Could you also tell me what was it that i was doing incorrectly